# ERROR : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query SQLLite

Tags: sql, android-studio, sqllite

Estoy trantado de guardar en la variable teléfono el valor del campo phone del usuario con id 1 de la base de datos, pero al intentar recuperarlo tengo el siguiente error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query SQLLite
```

PARTE DE LA CLASE DATABASE QUE CREA LA TABLA

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database creation sql statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_CONTACTS+ "(" + COLUMN_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_NAME+ " text not null,"
            + COLUMN_PHONE+ " text not null"
            +");";
```

LA CONSULTA ES LA SIGUIENTE:

```
 public String primerContacto(){
     //Consultamos los datos
     //Cursor c = database.query(Database.TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[]{"phone"}, Database., null, null, null, null);

     Cursor c = database.query(Database.TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] {"phone"},
            "id like " + "'1'", null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
         c.moveToFirst();
         do {
            //Asignamos el valor en nuestras variables para usarlos en lo que necesitemos
            telefono = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("phone"));
         } while (c.moveToNext());
     }

     c.close();
     return telefono; }
```

¿A que puede debrse?

Comment: Donde inicializas database en el clase que contiene el método primerContacto() podrías agregar más código ?